# Adding EditText dynamically by pressing a Button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I want to add an "ingredient" EditText view next to a "quantity" EditText view, pressing an "add" Button. Here's the starting layout code:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ingredients_line_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_line_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ingredientsField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:hint="@string/ingredients"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/quantity"
        android:id="@+id/quantityField"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/add_ingredient_btn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_ingr_btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I implement the onClick method for the button, in the corresponding activity?

Comment: Do you want to just show a single EditText on the button click or want to add a new one every time the button is pressed?

Comment: I want to add a new one every time the button is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set `OnClickListener` for "add" button;
2. Create a view you want to add;
3. Find `ingredients_line_layout` layout and add your view to it.

See code below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    View button = findViewById(R.id.add_ingredient_btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ingredients_line_layout);
            EditText ingredient = new EditText(YourActivity.this);
            ingredient.setHint(R.string.ingredients);
            layout.addView(ingredient, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but how can I add each new EditText view in a different line of my LinearLayout?

Comment: @EdoardoTavilla Look at this line: `layout.addView(ingredient, 1)`. Second param is a position inside `LinearLayout`. Change it to add a view to a position you want. In my example I use constant value but you can calculate position dynamically.

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Write all views in the XML file, and hide "ingredient" EditText

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ingredients_line_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title_line_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/quantity"
        android:id="@+id/quantityField"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ingredientsField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:hint="@string/ingredients"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/add_ingredient_btn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/boxes_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_ingr_btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2:** Register onClick listener on add button.

```
addIngredientBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Step 3:** Visible "ingredient" on button click

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ingredientsField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

By this way, you can add EditText Dynamically.

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText etIngredient = new EditText(context); // pass Context here
etIngredient.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(..., ...)); // two Arguments such as LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
layout.addView(etIngredient);
```

You might wanna add weights to the layout holding the editText accordingly if there are two edit text beside each other.

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?